# How to remove or fix the date stamps of specific messages in Skype?

Tags: skype, database

In order to exerience Terraria events without waiting until Christmas I changed my system time from the current time (September) to December.

Skype messages that I received during this time were logged as if they were receieved in December, I thought that maybe this would be fixed when I changed back to September or at least new messages would go beneath the ones in December. However this is not the case and it is extremely annoying having to scroll down all the time to read messages as I type with a friend.

How can I remove or fix the date stamp of these messages in December?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the article
[Editing Skype history / messages / database](http://stefantsov.com/editing-skype-history-messages-database/),
use this procedure :

1. Download [SQLite Database Browser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser)
2. While Skype is closed, open its database at
   `C:\Users\<Windows-user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Skype\<Skype-user-name>\main.db`
3. Display the messages from December by entering :
   `select * from Messages where timestamp >= 1421020800`
4. Move these messages to September 1st by entering :
   `update Messages set timestamp = 1420761600 where timestamp >= 1421020800`
5. Click "Write changes"

The above timestamp numbers were calculated using the website 
[Unix Time Conversion page](http://onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm). Using this website page, I calculated the dates as follows :

```
1 December 2015 = 1421020800
1 September 2015 = 1420761600
```

Comment: Thanks, although in step 4, that doesn't work, instead of `timestamp - 259200` I put in `1420761600` instead and then it worked. Also might be worth saying you have to enter the code in the `Execute SQL` tab

Comment: Also step 5. You have to click "write changes" and then you can open up skype

Comment: Thanks, I modified the above procedure according to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://stefantsov.com/editing-skype-history-messages-database/

Basically it is showing that you have to use SQLite database browser and open the following file:

```
c:\Users<UserName>\Application Data\Skype\<SkypeUserName>\main.db
```

From there you can edit what you need, delete individual messages and what not using the SQL language.

Comment: External links can break, in which case your answer would contain no useful information.  For this reason, we ask that you include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  I suspect that the open bounty will probably protect your answer from deletion temporarily.  You might want to edit your answer to replace the link with the one in your comment or add it, and expand your answer so it's self contained.

Comment: I see thanks for the pointers so the guy above who wrote my answer but in a step by step guide is correct?

Comment: The link texts are different so unless somebody checked, they wouldn't realize you both pointed to the same source.  Your answer pretty much stops there.  Harrymc's solution is all here and the link is just attribution.  A step-by-step guide provides a really useful answer, but you don't necessarily have to go that far; just provide enough information to accomplish the solution without the link.  When you're competing for a bounty, though, the best answer wins.